# What is $P(Y=1)$?

Tags: probability, distributions

Let $X$ be the number of tosses of a fair coin required to get the first
head. If $Y | X = n$ is distributed as Binomial$(n, \frac{1}{2})$, then what is
$P(Y = 1)$?

```
(A) 4/9 
(B) 1/4 
(C) 1/3 
(D) 5/9
```

What I understand so far is that $X$ follows geometric distribution. The other part, I couldn't relate. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to solve it would be applying Total Probability Law:
$$P(Y=1)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(Y=1|X=n)P(X=n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\left(\frac{1}{4}\right)^n$$

Comment: Why multiply by n in the summation?

Comment: Try to write $P(Y=1|X=n)$

Comment: That will be $(1/2)^n$. Did I write correctly?

Comment: No, you forget ${n\choose 1}$, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution

Comment: So, the answer would be 1/4?

Comment: You can use online calculators (or hand calculate) to find the exact answer, I haven't calculated the sum, but it's good practice and not that hard. You should do it.

Comment: It can be proved that the sum of the summation equals q/((1-q)^2) = 4/9, where q = 1/4.